# Android: media "gallery" with no Bluetooth media access

Tags: android, media-player, bluetooth

I'm looking for an app to play certain media files but that doesn't start playing immediately when a Bluetooth speaker is connected. The reason is that I teach English and carry the audio files for the course on my phone; playing them on my default music player will interrupt my playlist (banal, yes, but I don't want that) and using apps like VLC has the disadvantage of automatic Bluetooth playback on connection, which is mildly annoying because sometimes I forget to close the "secondary" media player (VLC, etc) and when I get in my car, both my playlist and "Lesson 4, activity 5" start playing.

I am aware there are some apps that select the default player on Bluetooth connection, but they don't seem to work with my phone, or clash with other apps I have (for example, an app that sets volume levels on Bluetooth devices pairing).

Is there any app that doesn't have any access to Bluetooth media and just plays media files? I've been using the default Video player in my Samsung Galaxy S8+, but there's no shortcut icon for it anywhere and I cannot add complete directories to its playlist (useful for long lessons).

I am looking for a media player in general, not necessarily "audio only", even if it costs money or includes ads, for Android devices. If the app costs money, I'd like it to cost at most USD $5; more than that is quite expensive for me.

Comment: As the title asks for "music" but the body looks like "video": could you please clarify if an audio-only player would be an acceptable answer – or what other media types must be covered? Also, must the app be [tag:gratis] – or is a paid app OK as well (and if so, what would be the price limit)?

Comment: Great! I've edited it once more (and also replaced a tag: media-player sounds more suitable then). For audio-only, I guess some local-media [folder player](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/multimedia_music_folderplay) could fit in (watch out for the yellow stars, marking tracker-free apps). There are also some players for [Music & Video](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/multimedia_music_video). I cannot tell precisely which would fit your needs, though – but while waiting for good recommendations, you could check their descriptions.